Get Items - email not being triggered when a list value is not found. Possibly wrong power automate command being used?
Problem: When the number plate is not in the list, I can not get the 'no match found - email Facilities department' email to fire.
I've used the 'Get Items' command, as the 'Get Item' only allowed me to select 'ID' which is no good for my purposes.  'Get Items' allows me to filter on a list to check if a number plate is known to us.
e.g. 'DE11BOY' is the number plate of a rascal who's parked in the wrong place.  If you arrive at work and find he's parked there, to get his car shifted out the way you submit a form: just type his number plate and click 'submit' (see picture below).  This triggers power automate into action.
In the picture below you see two 'known' number plates, MA22OLE and AA99ABC.  These values are stored in a list called 'WMT Finder'.
Outputs

If the number plate does exist it should trigger a 'YES' email to be sent (yes - the number plate is known, it emails a manager - tell so-and-so to move their car.

Likewise, the flow should trigger 'NO' email for when the number plate is not in the WMT Finder list - the email notifies the Facilities department to investigate.


Here's the process of what I want to achieve.

Power Automate

Form submitted, the compose actions get rid of any spaces and make the number plate capitalised.  This makes it match up with the format of the list data (no spaces, all capitalised).
Next bit...'Get Items' - compare the value of the 'DE11BOY' number plate vs what's stored in the list.  ('DE11BOY' is not a known vehicle, its number plate hasn't been logged here, so it should trigger the NO email).


Reminder of the problem
When the vehicle does exist, the email is sent.
When no number plate is found in the list (DE11BOY is not known), the email does not send.
I suspect the 'Get Items' command does not work as I intend it to.  PStork's answer here suggests to me that I am misusing the 'Get Items' command; "...you can't query on null fields" - is mine a 'null field' is no number plate is found in my list??
Do I need to use an array instead?
Screenshot of flow with the changes recommended by Matiur.

The 'yes' (green) email is sent when the number plate is not found.  The 'no' (red) email is sent when the number plate is found.
As you can see it works using the 'Get Items' command.

[Get Items] returns any array, and you can check if the array is empty (length=0) or it has items. Based on that you could decide in PA which email to send.
See the example below.
length(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])




wow, thanks Matiur, that's done the trick!
